Kuala Lumpur layover Visa on Arrival Rules for Indians
I have a 16 hour layover (7:30 am to 23:35 pm) at Kuala Lumpur and am planning to visit KL during the layover.
I understand that there is a Visa on Arrival provision for Indians, but I wanted to know the process for the same.
Both flights are with the same airline so I'm assuming that I would not be required to take the checked luggage with me during the layover.
Is there an online declaration to be filled?
Are any documents needed for the Visa and any MYR cash requirements to be fulfilled?
Thanks!

Have you checked any advice from the airline on this topic? What has other research revealed so far?

This question is similar to: Kuala Lumpur Layover KLIA2 from Thailand to India flight. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Traveller That advice might be outdated.

@AnishSheela you are correct, Indian citizens are eligible for visa-free visits to Malaysia through the end of 2024; the advice in the proposed duplicate is not accurate for now.

Malaysia provides visa on arrival and that too free of cost for Indian nationals. This scheme is currently valid till December 2024.
You need the following documents.

The passport validity must be at least six (6) months
Confirmed Return Flight Tickets (Onward boarding pass will be OK)
Confirmed Hotel Booking (Not required in your case, as you are not staying the night)
Proof of sufficient financial provisions (They usually don't check this, but you should have sufficient money to spend.)
Compulsory online submission of the Malaysia Digital Arrival Card (MDAC)

Source: https://www.kln.gov.my/web/ind_new-delhi/requirement_foreigner
